# React Native Calendars (wix) - Resource View

Tags: javascript, react-native, calendar, expo, velo

I've been struggling with this problem during this week, I've trying to find out how to achieve a resource view for React Native, I tried the wix calendar one but I can't get this view so far. Does anyone can help me or have any other library I can give it a try? also tried with React Native Calendar Event library.

this is my code so far:

```
<View style={styles.screen}>
    <CalendarProvider
     style={{ marginBottom: 40 }}
     date={currentDate}
     onDateChanged={() => console.log('onDateChanged')}
     onMonthChange={() => console.log('onMonthChanged')}
     showTodayButton={true}
     disabledOpacity={0.6}
    >
    <ExpandableCalendar
        showWeekNumbers={false}
        showScrollIndicator={false}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        showSixWeeks={false}
        firstDay={1}
        markedDates={marked}
    />
    <TimelineList
        key={1}
        events={eventsByDate}
        timelineProps={timelineProps}
        showNowIndicator
        scrollToFirst
        initialTime={INITIAL_TIME}
    />
    </CalendarProvider>
</View>
```

this is what I'm looking for

[Resource View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KqIq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON for your eventsByDate should look like this. The key should be an array of the dates that event is.

```
export const eventsByDate = {
  ["2023-02-11"]: [
    {
      start: "2023-02-11T10:48:00.000Z",
      end: "2023-02-11T12:48:00.000Z",
      title: "Merge Request to React Native Calendars",
      summary: "Merge Timeline Calendar to React Native Calendars",
    },
    {
      start: "2023-02-11T11:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2023-02-11T12:48:00.000Z",
      title: "test item",
      summary: "bladiebla",
    },
    {
      start: "2023-02-11T15:23:28.771Z",
      end: "2023-02-11T19:23:28.771Z",
      title: "Meeting A",
      summary: "Summary for meeting A",
      color: "lightgrey",
    },
  ],
}
```

Good luck!